# Json hash save into relational database in rows and columns

Tags: json, oracle, plsql

I want to read the values from json and need to create a new json so is there any way that
we can save json in table and columns in oracle that will help to perform calculation on that. calculation is too complax.

Here is the json sample and json has many hash and

```
{
  "agri_Expense": {
    "input": 6000,
    "max": 7500,
    "check": 7500
  },
  "income3": {
    "Hiring_income": 239750
  },
  "Operational_Cost1": [
    {
      "Field_input3": 10000,
      "Minimum": "0.05",
      "Check_Input": 26750,
      "Tractor_Cost": "Maintenance"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: what's your DB version? 12- or 12+ ?

Comment: database version is 12c

Comment: Why do you want (or think there can be) an answer that is specific to the PL/SQL Developer *client* - that's what re-adding that tag is saying? And why PL/SQL when this can probably be done in plain SQL? I say 'probably' because it isn't clear what you need to do or what the issue is. What does 'many hash' mean? Is the JSON you show the input or output, what calculation are you doing, and why do you need to use intermediate relational  tables to do it?

Comment: ive take the few lines from json as json is too long and want to insert in tables and column format so that i can do the calculation. 
Calculation-> I have to pick the few values from lookup table few from json and then calculate once all calculation done then need to create the json so what is the best way to cater this requirement.

Comment: What feature of [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/products/pl-sql-developer) are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Willam Didn't get your question.

Comment: You had tagged this with [plsqldeveloper] and then when the tag got removed you put it back. That tag is for questions on how to use features of that particular IDE; it is not for questions on generic code where you just happen to be coding using that IDE but could equally use any other IDE.

Comment: i want to achive in plsql code that's why i tagged plSQL developer.

Comment: Why PL/SQL? PL/SQL is Oracle's procedural language and is not the same as Oracle's dialect of SQL. You cannot create tables in PL/SQL; you want SQL for that.

Comment: [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/products/pl-sql-developer) (follow the link) is a desktop tool. The tag is meant for questions about that, not the PL/SQL programming language. In any case, it seems this can be done in SQL (the query language) without any procedural code.

Comment: got it always related to plsql programming we need to tag plsql community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need PL/SQL, and can do it entirely in SQL.

> I want to read the values from json [...] so is there any way that
> we can save json in table and columns in oracle

Yes, use SQL to create a table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( json_column CLOB CHECK ( json_column IS JSON ) )
```

and then `INSERT` the value there:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name ( json_column ) VALUES (
  '{'
  || '"agri_Expense": {"input": 6000,"max": 7500,"check": 7500},'
  || '"income3": {"Hiring_income": 239750},'
  || '"Operational_Cost1": [{"Field_input3": 10000,"Minimum": "0.05","Check_Input": 26750,"Tractor_Cost": "Maintenance"}]'
  || '}'
)
```

then, if you want individual values, `SELECT` using `JSON_TABLE`:

```sql
SELECT j.*
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(
         t.json_column,
         '$'
         COLUMNS (
           agri_expense_input NUMBER PATH '$.agri_Expense.input',
           agri_expense_max   NUMBER PATH '$.agri_Expense.max',
           agri_expense_check   NUMBER PATH '$.agri_Expense.check',
           income3_hiring_income NUMBER PATH '$.income3.Hiring_income',
           NESTED PATH '$.Operational_Cost1[*]'
           COLUMNS (
             oc1_field_input3 NUMBER PATH '$.Field_input3',
             oc1_minimum NUMBER PATH '$.Minimum',
             oc1_check_input NUMBER PATH '$.Check_Input'
           )
         )
       ) j
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> AGRI_EXPENSE_INPUT | AGRI_EXPENSE_MAX | AGRI_EXPENSE_CHECK | INCOME3_HIRING_INCOME | OC1_FIELD_INPUT3 | OC1_MINIMUM | OC1_CHECK_INPUT
> -----------------: | ---------------: | -----------------: | --------------------: | ---------------: | ----------: | --------------:
>               6000 |             7500 |               7500 |                239750 |            10000 |         .05 |           26750
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b25fc1eb43dd526b97b7748367413b1f)*